# Update if the field don't contain a sub value

Tags: mysql

I record the ip address of visitor and store it into mysql database. If the visitor gets a different ip, it will also update the record. I use the following code to do the update and values in following example is just for testing.

```
insert into visiter_info values ('1344594088179','0','100.100.100.100','china','300x600','IOS','firefox','')
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                    ip_address=concat(ip_address,'|','100.100.100.100'),
                    location=concat(location,'|','china'),
                    screen_res=concat(screen_res,'|','300x600'),
                    os=concat(os,'|','IOS'),
                    brower=concat(brower,'|','firefox')
```

It works, but now problem comes, how can I check if there is a record in the database? like this: visitor comes again, with ip 100.100.100.100. Mysql don't know there is a record, and it will re-record. How to check that if contains a sub string before insert?

Comment: which columns are `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` in your table?

Comment: It seems you are using comma-separated columns (or rather `|`-separated columns). This is not good. Store one information-value on every field, not many.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if not exists(select * from visiter_info where ip_address='100.100.100.100')
    insert into visiter_info values ('1344594088179','0','100.100.100.100','china','300x600','IOS','firefox','') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
        ip_address=concat(ip_address,'|','100.100.100.100'), 
        location=concat(location,'|','china'), 
        screen_res=concat(screen_res,'|','300x600'), 
        os=concat(os,'|','IOS'), 
        brower=concat(brower,'|','firefox')
```